# What is the correct way to format the HTML to send to hotmail?

Tags: html, sendmail, hotmail

This go to inbox:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#052444">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="510">
<tr>
<td>
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"><b><a href="xxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Visite meu blog, comente e divulgue as mat&eacute;rias publicadas:</a></b></font>
<a href="xxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank"><img src="xxxxxxx" alt="Blogger" title="Blogger" style="display:inline; color:#F29600;" border="0" height="33" width="32" /></a>
<br /> 
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"><b><a href="xxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Siga meu perfil no twitter:</a></b></font>
<a href="xxxxxxxx" target="_blank"><img src="xxxxxx" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" style="display:inline; color:#F29600;" border="0" height="33" width="31" /></a>
<br /> 
<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"><b><a href="xxxxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Participe do meu Facebook:</a></b></font>
<a href="xxxxx" target="_blank"><img src="xxxxxx" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" style="display:inline; color:#F29600;" border="0" height="33" width="32" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but this always go to spam box:

```
<table id="body_holder" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550">
<tr>
<td height="160"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" alt="xxxxxx" title="xxxxxxx" style="display:block;" border="0" height="160" width="550" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#052444">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="510">
<tr>
<td height="30" valign="bottom"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Vamos juntos compartilhar id&eacute;ias e informa&ccedil;&otilde;es nas redes sociais!</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br /> <font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"> Marcos, <br /><br /> As redes sociais t&ecirc;m um potencial incr&iacute;vel para compartilhar id&eacute;ias e mobilizar pessoas em prol de uma causa. <br /><br /> Por isso, gostaria de convidar voc&ecirc; a interagir comigo nestes importantes canais de relacionamento. <br /><br /> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="33">
<tr>
<td valign="middle"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"><b><a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Visite meu blog, comente e divulgue as mat&eacute;rias publicadas:</a></b></font></td>
<td width="10"></td>
<td valign="middle"><a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank"><img src="xxxxxxxxx" alt="Blogger" title="Blogger" style="display:inline; color:#F29600;" border="0" height="33" width="32" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="33">
<tr>
<td valign="middle"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"><b><a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Siga meu perfil no twitter:</a></b></font></td>
<td width="10"></td>
<td valign="middle"><a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" style="display:inline; color:#F29600;" border="0" height="33" width="31" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="33">
<tr>
<td valign="middle"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"><b><a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Participe do meu Facebook:</a></b></font></td>
<td width="10"></td>
<td valign="middle"><a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank"><img src="xxxxxxxxx" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" style="display:inline; color:#F29600;" border="0" height="33" width="32" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="33">
<tr>
<td valign="middle"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial" size="2"><b><a href="xxxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;">Seja meu amigo no Orkut:</a></b></font></td>
<td width="10"></td>
<td valign="middle"><a href="xxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank"><img src="xxxxxxx" alt="Orkut" title="Orkut" style="display:inline; color:#F29600;" border="0" height="33" width="32" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" height="80" valign="middle"><font color="#FFFFFF">Se voc&ecirc; n&atilde;o quiser mais receber os emails do Jom&aacute;zio, <a href="xxxxxxxx" accesskey="clique" style="color:#F29600;">clique aqui</a>.</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table
```

>

i rly don't understand it.

Comment: `i rly don't understand it.` Yeah, same. What's the difference between the two examples you gave? Also, if it's spammy content, it's going to go to the spam folder...

Comment: Sure you're not trying to mask the sender? i.e. make the email look like it's coming from "abc@def.com" but it's really from abc@sender.com"?

Comment: nah, i set $php_mailer->Sender = 'same@same.com.br'; and $php_mailer->from = 'same@same.com.br'; idk why this second go to spam and the first go to inbox. i would like if someone explian it.

Answer (score 2):

That your message will be treated as spam may have several reasons:

1. Your Message is not correct HTML. Where is your html, head, body Tag?
2. Check the Mail-Headers of your received E-Mail. There might be informaiton about why its spam

Comment: Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=temperror ... this could be the error?

Comment: @jow: Provide full Mail Header pls.